# stateless widget column fixed white color

Tags: flutter, dart

Even if I give it a background colour, It's still white. it was working fine before but it's just unfixable

---

### Before Deleting the code

[image: 2]

---

### After Deleting the Code

[image: 1]

Comment: always add some code to your question that you have tried out to tackle the problem you are facing or the current code

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the column with a `Container()` widget, and pass the colour you want to the `color:` property. If the `color:` in the `Material()` widget is not working.

PS: This should work with `StatelefulWidgets` too.

**Like this:**

```
child: Material(
            //color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, // for me this was working.
            child: Container(
              // Its important to wrap a ListTile with a sized widget
              height: 300.0,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  ListTile(
                    title: Image.network('https://telegra.ph/file/fcae4efdaeb34e640ef1f.png'),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      'This is working',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

---

**OutPut:**

[image]

**Whole Code:**

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: Center(
            child: Material(
              //color: Colors.lightBlueAccent, // for me this was working.
              child: Container(
                // Its important to wrap a ListTile with a sized widget
                height: 300.0,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors.blueGrey,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    ListTile(
                      title: Image.network('https://telegra.ph/file/fcae4efdaeb34e640ef1f.png'),
                      subtitle: Text(
                        'This is working',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }
}
```